# Suggestions for a backup/archive system

Tags: backup, archive, rotation

I currently have a backup system that stores everything I want to backup in a single file. The file is approximately 15 GB. The backup is made nightly.

I'm looking for a system for a Linux server that will keep daily backups for 7 days, weekly backups for a month, and monthly backups indefinitely.

I'm trying to find a system like this, but don't really know where to start.

Is there an existing system that does this? Or am I better off writing my own?

Comment: I have to say that you can't have looked very hard if you're not even sure such a system exists.

Comment: Product and Service recommendations are off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/) and [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) are both widely-used and well-respected F/OSS backup utilities. Either one of them could be configured to maintain the backup aging/rotation that you specified.

If you wanted something more simple, you could look into [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) or [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/).

Comment: I have used BackupPC for a few small shops and had good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/) can be configured to do this. You can probably find something [here](http://linux.about.com/od/softbackup/Linux_Software_Backup_Solutions.htm) too.